# How do I recognize a System.Type instance representing SZ-Array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, reflection, clr

CLR uses distinct `System.Type` instances to represent SZ-arrays (Single-dimensional, Zero-based, aka vectors) and non-zero-based arrays (even if they are single-dimensional). I need a function that takes an instance of `System.Type` and recognizes if it represents a SZ-array. I was able to check the rank using `GetArrayRank()` method, but do not know how to check that it is zero-based. Would you please help me?

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var type1 = typeof (int[]);
        var type2 = Array.CreateInstance(typeof (int), new[] {1}, new[] {1}).GetType();

        Console.WriteLine(type1 == type2); // False

        Console.WriteLine(IsSingleDimensionalZeroBasedArray(type1));  // True
        Console.WriteLine(IsSingleDimensionalZeroBasedArray(type2)); //  This should be False
    }

    static bool IsSingleDimensionalZeroBasedArray(Type type)
    {
        // How do I fix this implementation?
        return type != null && type.IsArray && type.GetArrayRank() == 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
static bool IsSingleDimensionalZeroBasedArray(Type type)
{
    return type != null && type.IsArray && type == type.GetElementType().MakeArrayType();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faster than the above, without touching the type system, using just the Type's Name

```
public static bool IsSzArray( this Type type ) {
    if ( type != null && type.IsArray ) {
        string name = type.Name;
        int len = name.Length;

        return len > 2 && name[ len - 2 ] == '[';
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using .NET Core 2.0 or later (including the "new" .NET 5 or later), `System.Type` now has a more convenient [`IsSZArray` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isszarray) to do this for you. So the question's code could be rewritten:

```cs
static bool IsSingleDimensionalZeroBasedArray(Type type)
{
    return type?.IsSZArray ?? false;
}
```